# C++11 vector<bool> performance issue (with code example)

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, bitvector

I notice that vector is much slower than bool array when running the following code.

```
int main() 
{
    int count = 0;
    int n = 1500000;
    // slower with c++ vector<bool>
    /*vector<bool> isPrime;
    isPrime.reserve(n);
    isPrime.assign(n, true);
    */
    // faster with bool array 
    bool* isPrime = new bool[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        isPrime[i] = true;


    for (int i = 2; i< n; ++i) {
        if (isPrime[i])
            count++;
        for (int j =2; i*j < n; ++j )
            isPrime[i*j] = false;
    }

    cout <<  count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there some way that I can do to make `vector<bool>` faster ? Btw, both `std::vector::push_back` and `std::vector::emplace_back` are even slower than `std::vector::assign`.

Comment: you are accessing `isPrime` beyond its end, it should be `new bool[n]`

Comment: Don't use `vector<bool>` if you're super-concerned about performance. It's required by the standard to be very space efficient, and that has a performance cost.

Comment: How much of a slowdown are you talking about? You might want to add some timing examples to make this question more appealing.

Comment: You did compile with optimisation enabled?

Answer (score 22):

`std::vector<bool>` can have various performance issues (e.g. take a look at https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool).

In general you can:

- use `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` instead of `std::vector<bool>` (give a try to [`std::valarray<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) also).

  This requires more memory and is less cache-friendly but there isn't a overhead (in the form of bit manipulation) to access a single value, so there are situations in which it works better (after all it's just like your array of `bool` but without the nuisance of memory management)
- use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) if you know at compile time how large your boolean array is going to be (or if you can at least establish a reasonable upper bound)
- if Boost is an option try [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) (the size can be specified at runtime)

---

But for speed optimizations you have to test...

With your specific example I can confirm a performance difference only when optimizations are turned off (of course this isn't the way to go).

Some tests with g++ v4.8.3 and clang++ v3.4.5 on an Intel Xeon system (`-O3` optimization level) give a different picture:

```
                    time (ms)
                 G++      CLANG++
array of bool    3103     3010
vector<bool>     2835     2420    // not bad!
vector<char>     3136     3031    // same as array of bool
bitset           2742     2388    // marginally better
```

(time elapsed for 100 runs of the code in the answer)

`std::vector<bool>` doesn't look so bad (source code [here](http://rextester.com/SGKEVO84915)).

Comment: "Xeon" can be anything from P4 to Skylake.  Saying *which* Xeon (e.g. Haswell Xeon, or Exxxx v3) would be much more informative.  Those are pretty old compiler versions for modern hardware, too (not as big a deal if you aren't auto-vectorizing or using `-march=native`).

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right. It's a Xeon e3-1230v3 (using  `-march=native` switch). In my defence I would add that it wasn't meant to be a complete examination, but I'll add add test code and some more results as soon as I can.

Comment: You don't have to make a big deal out of timing this.  Just any time you post any perf numbers, the specific microarch and compiler version + options are essential.  e.g. clang++ 3.4.5 on a Haswell Xeon, `-O3 -march=native` would cover it.  BTW, clang 3.7.1 (current stable) auto-vectorizes for AVX2 significantly better than 3.4, in terms of the quality of the asm.  IDK how often that makes a perf diff, since memory bottlenecks often hide CPU bottlenecks.  http://llvm.org/apt/ has current versions of clang for debian-based Linux distros.

Comment: I confirm that the performance benefit of `std::vector<bool>` is not only observed on x86 processors, but also on my raspberry pi with gcc 8.3, with just a simple `-O2` switch. It's like 0.5s vs. 2.5s difference, with `std::vector<bool>` being 0.5s.

Answer (score 10):

`vector<bool>` may have a template specialization and may be implemented using bit array to save space. Extracting and saving a bit and converting it from / to `bool` may cause the performance drop you are observing. If you use `std::vector::push_back`, you are resizing the vector which will cause even worse performance. Next performance killer may be `assign` (Worst complexity: Linear of first argument), instead use `operator []` (Complexity: constant).

On the other hand, `bool []` is guaranteed to be array of `bool`.

And you should resize to `n` instead of `n-1` to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: It not only "may have" such a specialization, this is actually in the standard!

Comment: One workaround is to use `deque<bool>`. Or `vector<My_bool>`. :)

Comment: @Mohit Jain: template specialization should happen at compile time. It should affect run time performance, isn't it ?

Comment: @guoqing Implication of specialization would affect run time performance (for good or bad). In this case it may be good for space requirement and bad for execution time.

Comment: @guoqing You choose between `vector` and `list` before compile time, don't you? Yet it affects runtime performance.

Answer (score 7):

`vector<bool>` *can* be high performance, but isn't required to be.  For `vector<bool>` to be efficient, it needs to operate on many bools at a time (e.g. `isPrime.assign(n, true)`), *and* the implementor has had to put loving care into it.  Indexing individual bools in a `vector<bool>` is slow.

Here is a prime finder that I wrote a while back using `vector<bool>` and clang + libc++ (the libc++ part is important):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<bool>
init_primes()
{
    std::vector<bool> primes(0x80000000, true);
    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;
    const auto pb = primes.begin();
    const auto pe = primes.end();
    const auto sz = primes.size();
    size_t i = 2;
    while (true)
    {
        size_t j = i*i;
        if (j >= sz)
            break;
        do
        {
            primes[j] = false;
            j += i;
        } while (j < sz);
        i = std::find(pb + (i+1), pe, true) - pb;
    }
    return primes;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using dsec = duration<double>;
    auto t0 = steady_clock::now();
    auto p = init_primes();
    auto t1 = steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << dsec(t1-t0).count() << "\n";
}
```

This executes for me in about 28s (-O3).  When I change it to return a `vector<char>` instead, the execution time **goes up** to about 44s.

If you run this using some other std::lib, you probably won't see this trend.  On libc++ algorithms such as `std::find` have been optimized to search a word of bits at a time, instead of bit at a time.

See http://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html for more details on what std algorithms could be optimized by your vendor.