# Ignore a template spezialization and explicitly use the unspezialized template (std::vector<bool>)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, vector

While working on some old code it encountered an `std::unique_ptr<bool>` used for storing some bool-values (allocated in class constructor and used as an array).

When I tried to replace it with a `std::vector<bool>` I encountered a problem when I had to call a library function which takes a count and a pointer to the first boolean value (`const bool*`): There is a template specialization for `std::vector<bool>` which compresses 8 boolean values into one byte and therefore it is not possible to get a `bool*` pointer to the data without decompressing it first.

I have already found some solutions by Google search or the StackOverflow article [C++11 vector<bool> performance issue (with code example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932684/c11-vectorbool-performance-issue-with-code-example) but none of them are working for me (i.e. using a struct which contains a boolean would work, but it makes the code I try to simplify more complex; `std::valarray` does not provide a data() member)

There is also an article "[How to prevent specialization of std::vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384880/how-to-prevent-specialization-of-stdvectorbool)" but all solutions there are just workarounds and I am not convinced of the phrase "bool and unsigned char typically take the same amount of memory on their own" (mentioned at [compiler error when pointing to an element of std::vector<bool>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103695/pointing-to-an-element-of-stdvectorbool))

I also checked [Alternative to vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool) but we do not use boost in our solution and I am not willing to add this dependency for a single use.

My Question is: *Is there a way to ignore a template spezialization and explicitly use the unspezialized template for a type?*

For example

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class MyTemplate
{
public:
  static const int Value = 0;
}

template<>
class MyTemplate<double>
{
public: 
  static const int Value = 1;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // How can I make MyTemplate<double> ignore the spezialization and output 0?
  std::cout << "0==" << MyTemplate<double>::Value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about wrapping the book in some struct and continue from there?

Comment: Thats the "standard" solution, but for that to work with the library call I need a reinterpret_cast and when read or writing to an item I need to access the value member of the struct or I have to implement auto-boxing/unboxing in the struct which makes it way to complicated.

Comment: There are many ways to have an array of boolean values but bypassing the `vector<bool>` specialisation is not one of them.

Comment: The equivalent to `std::unique_ptr<bool>` would be `unique<bool>`. `std::vector<bool>` would be for `std::unique_ptr<bool[]>`...

Comment: Yes, thats one reason why I want to change this code. (are you sure you intended to write `unique<bool>` and not simply `bool`?)

Comment: Another solution might be to use `deque` or any other container

Comment: Do you really need `data()`? `&container[x]` will provide the pointer to the individual element you want for both `std::deque` and `std::valarray`. For `std::valarray`, `&container[0]` will give the same thing as `data()`, if you **really** need to do pointer arithmetic. Lastly, doing your own container for this data type is not too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO, because there is no guarantee an unspecialized template even exists.

In particular, it's quite reasonable for a compiler to have a specializations for all built-in types. So you typically see a compile-time dispatch: `vector<T>` forwards to `__VectorImplBuiltIn<T>` whenever `T` is a built-in type, and `__VectorImplBuiltIn<T>` in turn is specialized for each individual case. So `vector<float>` may use AVX to copy 4 floats at a time, and `vector<bool>` is packed.

Now there is no portable way to name that specific implementation class (it's literally an implementation detail) and that unspecialized `__VectorImplBuiltIn<T>` wouldn't even have a generic implementation because the compiler vendor would obviously know all built-in types.

In this scheme, the "normal" `vector<T>` would expand to `__VectorImplClassType<T>`, and that could be unusuable for `T==bool` because `bool` doesn't have a constructor.

So a perfectly reasonable scheme where `std::vector<T>` starts out by distinguishing types with and without constructor will make your idea impossible. And therefore it's no surprise that the ISO C++ Standard doesn't allow what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper struct that appears to behave identically to a `bool`, thus not requiring modification of code expecting it to be a `bool`:

```
struct B {
    bool val;
    B() {}
    B(bool val): val(val) {}
    operator bool&() { return val; }
    operator const bool&() const { return val; }
    bool* operator&() { return &val; }
    const bool* operator&() const { return &val; }
};
```

Then all of the following are possible:

```
B a = true, b(0);
a || 2 == 1;
5 ^ a;
const bool& x = a;
bool* y = &a;
a &= b;
!a;
```

Comment: That's the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932684/c11-vectorbool-performance-issue-with-code-example I wrote about in my question. But it adds a lot of complexity to the code and it still requires a reinterpret_cast for the library call.

Comment: @AndreasH. I don't see anything like this in that link. How does it require a reinterpret_cast?

Comment: When calling the library function which requires a `bool *` as you can see at https://ideone.com/exMf6X

Comment: @AndreasH. You could replace that part with `libraryFunction(&v[0])`, assuming that it is not also in the library.

Comment: That would work but - I am sorry - this is not an answer to my question _'Is there a way to ignore a template spezialization and explicitly use the unspezialized template for a type?'_

Comment: @AndreasH. In that case, the answer is "No."

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to your question exactly, although it may be an answer to your problems.

You said that you're trying to use a library that takes `bool *` as a parameter and that you are not using `std::valarray` because it doesn't have `data()`.

But doesn't the following work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

void doStuff(bool *x) {
    *x = true;
}

int main() {
    valarray<bool> v = {false,false,false,false,false,false};

    doStuff(&v[2]);

    for (bool b : v) {
        cout << b << endl;
    }

    //if you *really* want data(), &v[0] does the same
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ZrvsHh)

Note that [valarray is guaranteed to have contiguous memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143109/does-valarray-have-contiguous-memory-alignment).

---

An alternative is to create a replacement container, an example named `SimpleVector` is given [here](https://alala666888.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/simple-vector-implementation/) which only necessits a simple header file to be added, and the poster of the code references a book from Mark Allen Weiss.

In that implementation `begin()` behaves the same as `data()`.

Although the code is pre-c++11, so it doesn't implement a constructor for `&&`.

Comment: The library function takes a count and a pointer to the first bool. &v[0] would work as long as `valarray<bool>` stores its data as boolean values in a continuous block, but this behaviour is implementation dependent.

Comment: @AndreasH. actually it is guaranteed to work, I edited my post with a [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143109/does-valarray-have-contiguous-memory-alignment).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. This **is** a solution to my problem but I am afraid its not an acceptable answer to my question. 
I am sorry but I'll have to accept MSalters answer because its matches the question but at least I can give you an upvote.